# Ionic 4 Cordova Camera plugin not opening the Native gallery , it opens all files including photos

Tags: cordova, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using the camera plugin to access images in the gallery , ya I know that I should use : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
or
this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM

but both of them open all files ! I mean it open all files and make every file not image grayed out (can not be selected).
I used to open the gallery native ( only images / videos ) shows up . check below to know what I mean.
And I do not want to use photolibrary ( build on HTML )

[image: This is how the default when open through camera plugin]

Comment: What is the camera plugin you use?

Comment: the official cordova plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera